# Postgresql: Join another column on the least value greater than left column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here're two tables:

```
--Table A

id
1
4
7

--Table B
id
3
8
11
13
```

What I intend to implement is to join table `A` with `B` on `id` column, where right key's value is the smallest value greater than left key. For instance, `id=1` in table `A` should join with `id=3` in table `B`. Likewise, both `id=4` and `id=7` in table `A` should join with `id=8` in table `B`. Is there a good way to implement this in postgresql? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to look up the key is a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select min(b.id)
        from b
        where b.id > a.id
       ) as b_id
from a;
```

If you need additional columns from `b`, you can join this back to `b` or use a lateral join:

```
select a.*, b.*
from a left join lateral
     (select b.*
      from b
      where b.id > a.id
      order by b.id
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) b on true;
```

Note:  Your question says "greater than", so that is what the answer implements.  Usually in these situations, I would expect "greater than or equal to".  The adjustment for the queries is trivial.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! It's working, but.. it's super slow. Since table a is relatively small whereas table b is super big (20 million). Do u think there's any optimizations?

Comment: @JasonZhu . . . Start with an index on `b(id)`.  If that doesn't work for you, ask another question specifically about performance.

Comment: If you are using Snowflake, this does not work. Snowflake doesn't support fetch / limit / top / etc. in correlated subqueries

Comment: The question is tagged Postgres.